# What is the difference between HTML4 and HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

What the difference between HTML5 and HTML4?

Can they both be used for building pages or just designing?

Comment: HTML5 and HTML4 are document types.  HTML 4 and HTML 5 are revisions of the HTML standard.  Which one are you asking about?

Comment: HTML5 I wanna make a website so the attribute align doesn't work on HTML5 , besides I wanna edited pages so are they possible through HTML5?

Comment: HTML5 is a document type.  Are you asking if the HTML 5 standard defines a way to align an attribute?  [What's the key difference between HTML 4 and HTML 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134727/whats-the-key-difference-between-html-4-and-html-5).  Since I don't feel like having a discussion, I will just vote to close this question, because it currently is not clear.

Comment: If you have a page that works in HTML 4 but not HTML 5, just use the appropriate DOCTYPE declartion so the browser renders it to the v4 specifiation. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: This is a better question for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ but it's also far too broad.  Do some more research and then ask some specific questions at that sister site.

Answer (score 2):

There are various upgrades.  It is all backwards-compatible so whatever you have been doing in HTML4 will still work; just that there are now new features available.

Rather than try to list them here, please allow me to refer you directly to the authoritative document put out by W3.org:

[Differences between HTML4 and HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-html5-diff-20141209/)

Also, here is a quick summary:

[10 Differences Between HTML4 And HTML5](https://churchm.ag/differences-between-html4-html5/)